# Need Method Help for an Array List

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

For my homework, I had to write a program that prompts the cashier to enter all prices and names, adds them to two arrays lists, calls the method that I implemented, and displays the result and use 0 as the sentinel value. I am having difficulty coming up with a for loop in the method, I believe I have the condition right but I am having trouble with the statements. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   ArrayList<Double> sales = new ArrayList<Double>();
   ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
   System.out.print("Enter Number of Customers");
   double salesAmount;
   System.out.print("Enter Sales for First Customers");
   salesAmount = in.nextDouble();
   while(salesAmount != 0)
   {
       sales.add(salesAmount);
       System.out.println("Enter Name of Customer: ");
       names.add(in.next());
       System.out.println("Enter the next sales amount, 0 to exit: ");
       salesAmount = in.nextDouble();
   }

   String bestCustomer = nameOfBestCustomer(sales, names);

}

public static String nameOfBestCustomer(ArrayList<Double> sales, ArrayList<String> customers)
{
    String name = "";
    double maxSales;

    for (int i = 0; i < sales.size(); i++)
    {
        sales.size(name.get); <== it keeps saying "cannot find the symbol variable get"
    }
 return name;
}
```

Comment: Look at the [ArrayList documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  You'll need to look at the `size` and `get` methods, in particular.

Comment: Okay I tried that and it comes up with an error

Comment: `sales.size(name.get)`????????????  What were you hoping that statement would do?  First of all, to use `get`, you use the variable with your `ArrayList`, which is `names`, and then you have to give it the index of the element you want to get, like `names.get(i)`, and that returns a `String`, which you then need to do something with ...

Comment: As @ajb notes, you are clearly mixing your ideas.  Slow down and think about how you might describe your solution *in words* then try again to write your code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `maxSales` as the maximum in your loop.  Use the count of number of customers.  Inside the loop, check if `sales.get(i)` is greater than your current `maxSales`, and if it is...

(I will edit this and more if you still need.  But this should go a long way.)

Comment: When I put something like this it says it is still wrong String name = ""; double maxSales; for (int i = 0; i <= sales.size(); i++) { sales.size(name.get); } return name;When I put something like this it says it is still wrong String name = ""; double maxSales; for (int i = 0; i <= sales.size(); i++) { sales.size(name.get); } return name;

Comment: ArrayList.size() does not take any inputs.  And also name is a String- String does not have a "get" property.  Pay close attention to variables have what roles in your methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possible issues here, but I'll stick to answering what I think is the question that you've asked.

In your nameOfBestCustomer method, you'll want to loop from 0 to the end of either of your ArrayLists (as they both should be the same size).

```
for (int i = 0; i < sales.size(); i++)
{
...
}
```

Comment: When I put something like this it says it is still wrong String name = "";
        double maxSales;

        for (int i = 0; i <= sales.size(); i++)
        {
            sales.size(name.get);
        }
     return name;

Comment: Java uses zero based indexing.  You want your conditional in the for loop to stop one before sales.size().  You should be using i < sales.size() rather than i <= sales.size().

Comment: Okay thanks for helping me, but when I changed that it is says that it "cannot find the symbol for the variable get"

Comment: @cobaltduck seems to have answered this one.  The size method of ArrayList (and in general) takes no parameters.  The get method of ArrayList takes an int index.  You'll want to use your loop counter i there.